# Sphinx Storage Engine for MySQL reindex on record insert

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

Do I have to run the indexer each time I add new records unto my tables? Is there no other way around this? Whenever I add a new record I always have to do `indexer test1 --rotate` on my `searchd` service.

- I am using `ha_sphinx.dll` on windows version 1.11 r2616.
- MySQL version is 5.5.9